# i have fetched the list of users pages but how can i make get the access token for particular page?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

`I have fetched all the pages of users using manage_page permission, using this code :

> ```
>      <fb:login-button perms="manage_pages"
>              onlogin="getPages()">   list of pages</fb:login-button>
>
>    <ul id="pages"></ul>
>
> <script>
>
>     window.getPages = function() {
>
> FB.api('/me/accounts', function(resp) {
>
>     var ul = document.getElementById('pages');
>
>     for (var i=0, l=resp.data.length; i<l; i++) {
>
>         var
>         page= resp.data[i];
>         li = document.createElement('li');
>         li.innerHTML = "Name: " + page.name ;
>         ul.appendChild(li);
>     }
>    }); }; </script>
>
>
>   <div id="fb-root"></div>
>
>    <script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
>
>  <script>  FB.init({ 
>    appId:'XXXXXXXXXXXXX', cookie:true, 
>    status:true, xfbml:true   });
>
>   </script>
> ```

**Output for the above code :**

- -> -page1
- > -page2
- > -page3
- > -page4

//here it is displaying only the list of pages but i want when the user clicks on
    page1 it should redirect them to their facebook page directly.

How can i include/add  this code into the above codings and use it ?

> https://graph.facebook.com/PAGE_ID/tabs?app_id=APP_ID&method=POST
>   &access_token=PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this line:

`li.innerHTML = "Name: " + page.name ;`

to

`li.innerHTML = "Name: <a href='http://facebook.com/"+page.id+"'>"+page.name+"</a>";`